# Rewriting a VueJS Component using JSX and the Render Function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jsx, vue-component

I have the following VueJS component:

```
Vue.component('label-ui', {
    props: ['type', 'size', 'color', 'position'],

    template: `
        <div :class="[type, size, color, position]" class="ui labels">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
```

I want to rewrite this so that I can dynamically set the html tag of the template - similar to what I do with this code:

```
  props: ['tag', 'attributes'],
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(this.tag || 'div', {attrs: this.attributes || {}}, this.$slots.default);
  }
```

However, I want to use the JSX syntax - as noted here:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX

I cannot figure out, though, how to do this using the JSX format.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: To start with, do you have the [plugin mentioned](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx)?

Comment: Yes, I have installed that plugin

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you've got Webpack with the correct babel plugins set up for transpiling.

JSX isn't natively supported by the browser, a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) will transpile (convert from JSX to Javascript) from JSX, which isn't understood by the browser, to a format that is understood by the browser.

That's going to be the first step you need to take and probably what you're missing.

Comment: As far as I know, I have installed all of the required plugins installed and webpack properly configured.  My problem is figuring out how I should write the render function with JSX properly.

Comment: Here is how I configured my webpack, package.json and babelrc files:  https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkID1VIBnJlCzOuwTQj

Comment: I can't get your config to load properly

Comment: It loads fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just install [babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx)
I've got nothing to add to the configuration. It worked directly.